# Properties contactenation failed

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-boot, properties-file

I work on a project for a few weeks and I have some issues with the properties files.

I use two properties files :

- project_default.properties (generic configuration, environment independent)
- project_custom.properties (environment specific configuration)

project_default.properties

```
project.url=
project.url.front=${project.url}/index.html#
project.uri.link=${project.url.front}/element/{0}/step
```

project_custom.properties

```
project.url=http://domainName.extension
```

On my own server (same OS, JVM and Tomcat version):
No problem !

On every server of my client :
Error when using **project.uri.link**

I have patched it for the moment by bypassing the concatenation but it is not professional.

Have ever met this kind of problem ? Any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Extra information:

- The file **project_default.properties** is packaged inside the WAR
- The file **project_custom.properties** is externalized.

Comment: AFAIK, this string interpolation works in the `application.properties` file, but probably not in just any regular properties file in Spring Boot (See [Placeholders in properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.util.Properties will not support this resolved value into another..
As it is meant for simple string values.

Property keys and values are suppose to be Strings. No processing happens to them, so you can't refer to another value in a value.

Look at Apache Configuration,

http://commons.apache.org/configuration/

It supports Variable Interpolation probably that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I am looking for.
Does Apache Common Configuration support annotations (don't find) ?

Comment: I believe not.. you might need to use it API calls to achieve this